# Javascript Array Sort() Index before and after

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, indexing

I have an indexed of of objects:

```
indexArray = [
    {obj 1},
    {obj 2},
    ...
    {obj n}
];
```

I apply a sorting algorithm to it and the indexArray ends up being mixed up:

```
indexArray = [
    {obj 77},
    {obj 36},
    ...
    {obj 8}
];
```

If there was one element in the original array whose before and after Index I want to keep track of. For example, obj 36 was at index[35] before sorting, and the new index is index[1]. How would I determine the new index.

Could I hold on to the element/obj36 in a temp variable before the sort, and then after the sort, ask indexArray the current index of obj36? And if so, how?

Comment: Depends on your sorting algorithm.  Are you using the javascript default sort?

Comment: Yes. I was just wondering there was more efficient way then temp variable and loop to find it. But I realize keeping a +- counter as the object moves position through array is worse.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using a temp variable to refer to it and then look for it in the sorted array can make the trick. You can use the `Array.prototype.indexOf` method if it's available or just loop to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

- Create the array.
- Copy it to another array.
- Sort the original one.
- Search for ocurrences of the itens of the sorted in the unsorted.

Take a look:

```
// original array of objects
var a = [{
    n: 5
}, {
    n: 3
}, {
    n: 7
}, {
    n: 1
}];

// create a copy of the original (concats the original with a empty one)
var b = a.concat([]);

// sorting
a.sort( function( left, right ) {
    return left.n - right.n;
});

// print a values
for ( var i in a ) {
    console.log( a[i].n );
}

// print b values
for ( var i in b ) {
    console.log( b[i].n );
}

// searching...
for ( var i in a ) {
    console.log( "value: " + a[i].n +
                 " original index: " + b.indexOf(a[i]) +
                 " current index: " + i );
}
```

Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp) for some info about Array functions.